# difference between lastLogin and login in user_ table in liferay

Tags: liferay

Whats the difference between lastLogin and Login in the User_ table in liferay? It appears that at times the login field is the later of the 2 dates implying that it could be the last time the user logged in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are correct.

`Login` field implies the latest login action data, which includes `loginDate` and `loginIP`, whereas the lastLogin field includes the previous `Login` data.

Here is the two consecutive login data of a **User** :

First Time Login :

```
         lastName: Element
         jobTitle: 
        loginDate: 2014-06-13 11:21:54
          loginIP: 127.0.0.1
    lastLoginDate: 2014-06-13 11:15:23
      lastLoginIP: 127.0.0.1
```

Second time login :

```
         lastName: Element
         jobTitle: 
        loginDate: 2014-06-16 06:33:23
          loginIP: 127.0.0.1
    lastLoginDate: 2014-06-13 11:21:54
      lastLoginIP: 127.0.0.1
```

So as you can see the data is swapped from `login` to `lastLogin` in current login attempt.